# overide site notice dashlet to user dashboard

Tags: share, alfresco, dashlet

I tried to do a wellcome notes dashlet into my alfresco share user dashboard, that is edited by the admin.
so i just overide the site notice dashlet, but i cant figured out how to save the components properties like the text and title.

now when i edit the title or text after a page refresh i lose everything, and every user gets its own content.

im kind newbie in this.
I apreciate an help.
my regards.

so this is how i made it:

[the wellcome.get.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iNzK.png)

[the welcome.get.ftl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVt3b.png)

[wellcomeTo.get.desc.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1NCb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below article for adding the custom Dashlet and its works perfectly fine for me. Give a try and let me know if any issues.

Custom New Dashlet: http://www.krutikjayswal.com/2016/07/alfresco-share-dahslet.html

Customizing the Dashboard: https://docs.alfresco.com/6.1/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-js-customize.html